# password validation no Character sequence ( kotlin android studio )

Tags: android, regex, kotlin, validation, passwords

I have the task to create a password validation that has to consider some things. The only problem I have is that one of the criteria of the password validation is that the password must not contain any sequences, e.g. (12345), (abcdef), (asdfghjk). I have already searched a lot and do not know how to implement this. Can anyone help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't give much detail into what code you already have and what you're stuck on about the logic, here's a very generalized description of a strategy you could use to do this:

1. Create a `List<Iterable<Char>>` that contains all the possible strings of characters that could be considered a range. For example:

```
    val charRuns = listOf(
        '0'..'9',
        'a'..'z',
        'A'..'Z',
        "qwertyuiop".asIterable(),
        //...
    )
```

2. Iterate these runs to fill a `MutableMap<Char, MutableSet<Char>>`, where the keys are any of the characters from the runs, and the values are sets of all the chars that if they appear next in a string should be considered a consecutive sequence.
3. Iterate the potential password String, using the map to check the subsequent Char of each Char to see if it should be considered part of a sequence. Use a counter variable to count the current size of sequence found so far, and reset it whenever a non-sequence is found. If it ever rises above your threshold for allowable sequence size, reject the password immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it.
I also check that there is no sequence in backwards, for example (4321, dcba).

```
private fun noSequenzes(password: String) : Boolean {
    val charRuns = listOf(
        '0'..'9',
        'a'..'z',
        'A'..'Z',
        "qwertzuiop".asIterable(),
        "asdfghjklöä".asIterable(),
        "yxcvbnm".asIterable()
    )
    var map = emptyMap<Char, MutableSet<Char?>>()
    charRuns.forEach { run ->
        run.forEach { char ->
            val charsToAdd = mutableSetOf(run.elementAtOrNull(run.indexOf(char) + 1))
            if (run is CharRange) {
                charsToAdd.add(run.elementAtOrNull(run.indexOf(char) - 1))
            }
            if (map.contains(char)) {
                map.get(char)!!.addAll(charsToAdd)
            }
            else {
                map = map.plus(Pair(char, charsToAdd))
            }
        }
    }
    var sequenceCounter = 1
    var recentChar: Char? = null
    password.toCharArray().forEach { c ->
        recentChar?.let { rc ->
            val isSequence = map.any { me -> me.key == rc && me.value.contains(c) }
            if (isSequence) {
                sequenceCounter = sequenceCounter + 1
            }
            else {
                sequenceCounter = 1
            }
            if (sequenceCounter >= 3) {
                return false
            }
        }
        recentChar = c
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

time-locked login verification

create var

```
private lateinit var editTextUsername: EditText
private lateinit var editTextPassword: EditText
private lateinit var buttonLogin: Button
private var attemptsLogin = 0
private val handler: Handler = Handler()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    supportActionBar?.hide()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    editTextUsername = findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername)
    editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword)
    buttonLogin = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin)

}
```

create logic

```
fun loginButtonClicked(view: View) {
    val user = editTextUsername.text.toString()
    val password = editTextPassword.text.toString()

    if (user == "User" && password== "password") {
        
        startActivity(Intent(this, screen_home::class.java))
        finish()
    } else {
        
        attemptsLogin++
        if (attemptsLogin >= 3) {
            loginBloked()
            handler.postDelayed({
                attemptsLogin = 0
            }, 2000) 
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "User/Password Invalid !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

      

private fun loginBloked() {
    editTextUsername.backgroundTintList = resources.getColorStateList(R.color.red)
    editTextPassword.backgroundTintList = resources.getColorStateList(R.color.red)
    editTextUsername.text.clear()
    editTextPassword.text.clear()
    arrayOf(editTextUsername, editTextPassword).forEach { it.isEnabled = false }
    arrayOf(buttonLogin).forEach { it.isEnabled = false }

    Toast.makeText(this, "wait 2s!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    handler.postDelayed({
        arrayOf(editTextUsername, editTextPassword).forEach { it.isEnabled = true }
        arrayOf(buttonLogin).forEach { it.isEnabled = true }
    }, 2000) 
}
```

remember xml:

```
android:onClick="loginButtonClicked"
```